# New windows 10 hp laptop will not retain synaptics touchpad one finger scroll. Reverts after booting

Tags: laptop, touchpad

Every time i boot my hp laptop (Hp 15-f337wm) I have to go through process to enable single finger scrolling in settings despite having applied and ok'd the setting.  It's a pain in ass.  Don't know if its issue of too new laptop with too new windows version. It really gets old because takes 8-10 steps every time. Help

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem on a Hp,  just try different version numbers of the synaptics trackpad driver, some work,  others don't,  and some kind of work but dont save the settings.